# How can i prevent the possibility to select a particular column in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to disable the possibility to select particular columns in a Jtable.

It's easy to disable the selection of certain rows with using the `DefaultListSelectionModel` class

But I don't know how to do that for columns.

Can any one give me a clue to implement this feature ?

Comment: You will probably need to replace the `ListSelectionModel` which is been used by the `TableColumnModel`

Comment: Can you override columnSelectionChanged method on jtable, won't it get hit when a column is selected?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method `isCellEditable` and implement as you want for example,

try this :

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
   @Override
   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
       //Only the column nb 2
       return column == 2; 
   }
};
table.setModel(tableModel);
```